# Should it be "no sign of" or "no signs of"?

Tags: negation, grammatical-number

I'd like to say:

The calm, balmy evening air showed no sign of the carnage that would ensue.

My question is: should it be "no sign of" or "no signs of"?

Obviously the word "sign" is countable noun in this context.  One sign.  Two signs.  But NO SIGN means zero sign.

Should I use sign in singular form "sign" or plural form "signs" here?

Answer (score 1):

The writer could choose either.

Let's assume the intention is to convey a dramatic change of mood.

In the context, the singular is more appropriate. The intended meaning here is of a state of calm. The atmosphere has nothing about it that would indicate a negative state was to come. If more than a single, isolated sign were present, the change would be less surprising. If there was just one sign the change might be suspected, but probably dismissed. No sign at all increases the sense of suspense.

The more signs, or the increase in number as well as the rate of increase all contribute to the build-up of drama and suspense. Think of the minor earthquakes that noone really took any notice of before Vesuvius erupted in AD 79, or Hitchcock's Birds.

Answer (score 1):

The singular "no sign of" is the more emphatic of the two grammatically correct options, as it conveys that there was not even a single sign.

Answer (score 0):

When tracking an animal, **"sign"** is the name of the traces that animals leave - spoor, tracks, hair all together.  So even if you count signs and get more than one, you can still use the "plural" sign as a hunting analogy.

I don't think there is any good reason for ruling out sign or signs in context.